# Remove items from array using id with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a function like this: `pickListSelect array` is has all id (numbers) to delete objects in `source array`, and `target array` it is to push elements deleted from `source array`.

```
    function copy(pickListSelect, source, target) {

         var i, id;

         for (i = 0; i < pickListSelect.length; i++) {
              id = pickListSelect[i];              
              source.splice(id,1);
         }
         pickListSelect = [];
   }
```

So what I need is delete specific object from `source arra`y. I tried with that code but for example if I need to delete object with id=5, it only deleted item 5 from the list.

The structure of source array is this:

```
    [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]
    0:Object
    plantId:1
    plantName:"Plant 1"

...the rest of others are similar object
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find plant in your `source` by `plantId` first, and then delete it from original array and push to target. Open console and it should log deleted plants:

```js
var plants = [
    {
        plantId: 1,
        plantName: 'plant 1'
    },
    {
        plantId: 2,
        plantName: 'plant 2'
    },
    {
        plantId: 3,
        plantName: 'plant 3'
    },
    {
        plantId: 4,
        plantName: 'plant 4'
    }
];

function copy(pickListSelect, source, target) {
    var i, id, el;

    for (i = 0; i < pickListSelect.length; i++) {
        id = pickListSelect[i];
        el = findPlant(source, id);
        source.splice(source.indexOf(el), 1);
        target.push(el);
    }
}

function findPlant (arr, id) {
    return arr.filter(function (plant) {
        return plant.plantId == id
    })[0]
}

var test = [];

copy([2,3], plants, test);

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 2):

When you use .splice you need to pass in the start index at which to splice and the amount of items to splice, try this:

```
source.splice(i,1); // i is your starting index here


array.splice(start, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]])
```

[MDN on .splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Now in your actual code you need to check to see if the id matches and **then** splice using the above code:

```
function copy(pickListSelect, source, target) {

     var i, id;

     for (i = 0; i < pickListSelect.length; i++) {
          if (pickListSelect[i].id === someId) {              
            source.splice(i,1);
          }
     }
     pickListSelect = [];
 }
```

Comment: see edit...you need to check to see if the ids are the same too

Comment: "pickListSelect" array only contains of all id to delete.
But on "source" is an array of objects, which each object contains id and plant name properties.

Comment: pickListSelect[i].id it is not possible.
The structure array is [1, 2] only id

Answer (score 1):

You're not looking up the index of the source array with a matching id. It might be better to do something like this.

```
var idsToRemove = {};

// build an object of ids to remove (effectively a hashset)
for (var i = 0; i < pickSelectList.length; i++) {
    idsToRemove[pickSelectList[i]] = true;
}

// loop through the source array to find any objects with ids to remove
for (var j = 0; j < source.length; j++) {
    if (source[j].plantId in idsToRemove) {
        target.push(source.splice(j, 1));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at this fiddler [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jhpz32hd/).
I have used underscore.js to find the correct element from source and move it to the target array.

```
var copy = function(pickListSelect, source, target) {
    for (i = 0; i < pickListSelect.length; i++) {
      id = pickListSelect[i];
      var deleteIndex = _.findIndex(source, {Id: id});
            var deletedItem = source.splice(deleteIndex, 1);
            target.push(deletedItem[0])
    }
        pickListSelect = [];
    return target;
  }
```